# GWT RequestFactory: updates not propagated to cascaded object

Tags: gwt, jpa, requestfactory

I have an entity Company with a referenced object ItemVersion and I use JPA (eclipselink) as persistence layer. A code extract is given here:

```
@Entity
public class Company{
    private String instance;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_item_version_id")
    private ItemVersion itemVersion;
}

@Entity
public class ItemVersion{
    private String comment;
...
}
```

I can create a Company object and persist it. I can also find the new object, update the attribute "instance" and persist it and everything works fine.
When I change the attribute "comment" of the referenced ItemVersion object, this change is not stored on the server side.

The create/update test code looks like:

```
final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
final AftdRequestFactory requestFactory = GWT.create(AftdRequestFactory.class);
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus);

final CompanyRequest request = requestFactory.companyRequest();
final CompanyProxy newCompany = request.create(CompanyProxy.class);
newCompany.setInstance("1");
ItemVersionProxy newVersion = request.create(ItemVersionProxy.class);
newVersion.setComment("first comment");
newCompany.setItemVersion(newVersion);

request.persist().using(newCompany).fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void arg0) {
    final CompanyRequest request2 = requestFactory.companyRequest();
    Request<CompanyProxy> p = request2.findCompany(1L).with("itemVersion");
    p.to(new Receiver<CompanyProxy>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CompanyProxy response) {
            final CompanyRequest request3 = requestFactory.companyRequest();
            final CompanyProxy editableCompany2 = request3.edit(response);
            editableCompany2.setInstance("2");
            editableCompany2.getItemVersion().setVersionNumber(2);
            request3.persist().using(editableCompany2).fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void arg0) {
                    // persist company version
                    System.out.println("company updated");
```

However, the update for "instance" and "comment" goes over the wire (checked wich wireshark between client and server), but in the persist method of Company, the referenced ItemVersion object and its "comment" attribute is not updated while "instance" is updated and therefore the old comment is stored.

The persist method of Company looks like:

```
public void persist() throws PersistenceException {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        Company existingEntity = findCompany(getId());
        if (existingEntity == null) {
            em.persist(this);
        } else {
            setId(existingEntity.getId());
            em.merge(this);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
}
```

The work around with a search and depending on the search result the em.persist or em.merge is necessary, because a simple persist does not store any updates.

Comment: Are you using then OpenSessionInView, aka session-per-request, pattern on the server-side? (or in other words, how are you managing the lifetime of your JPA `EntityManager`s?)

Comment: I have added Company.persist() code above. I also guess the root cause of the problem is located on the server side. According to my understanding, I should see the updated object including all updated references in Company.persist(), but as I said, I only see the updates of Company, not of ItemVersion.
Right now, I did not find any complete source code example which uses RequestFactory *and* JPA in combination. Can you provide a link? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You **MUST** use the open-session-in-view/session-per-request pattern (i.e. sharing the same `EntityManager` instance for the lifetime of the request) with RequestFactory; see https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7827 for details.

Comment: Right, that was the problem. Using the same EntityManager instance solved the problem. Thank you!